# Combine columns in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, loops, lambda

I want to combine eight columns into two columns in a DataFrame. The two columns would be Date and Moon Phase, and date should be an index and datetime.  It should be in order of phases - New Moon, First Q, Full Moon, Third Q. Concatenate and merge don't work because it is one DataFrame.

Example:

```
     Date      Moon Phase   Date     Moon Phase    Date    Moon Phase   Date      Moon Phase
0 2020-08-18 New Moon 2020-08-25 First Quarter 2020-09-01 Full Moon 2020-09-10 Third Quarter
1 2020-09-17 New Moon 2020-09-23 First Quarter 2020-10-01 Full Moon 2020-10-09 Third Quarter
2 2020-10-16 New Moon 2020-10-23 First Quarter 2020-10-31 Full Moon 2020-11-08 Third Quarter
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get the Example into a DataFrame format and when trying to edit it to show that it wouldn't let me edit it.  The first line is the columns and the rest is the phases of the moon..  The names of the columns repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
        ['2020-08-18', 'New Moon', '2020-08-25', 'First Quarter', '2020-09-01', 'Full Moon', '2020-09-10', 'Third Quarter'],
        ['2020-09-17', 'New Moon', '2020-09-23', 'First Quarter', '2020-10-01', 'Full Moon', '2020-10-09', 'Third Quarter'],
        ['2020-10-16', 'New Moon', '2020-10-23', 'First Quarter', '2020-10-31', 'Full Moon', '2020-11-08', 'Third Quarter']
       ]

columns = ['Date', 'Moon Phase', 'Date', 'Moon Phase', 'Date', 'Moon Phase', 'Date', 'Moon Phase']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

###### create a column with a list of lists with the columns in pairs [[date, phase], ..., ]

```
df['tmp'] = df.apply(lambda row: [[row[i], row[i+1]] for i in range(0, 8, 2)], axis=1)
```

###### separates the list of lists into rows

```
df = df.iloc[:, 8:].explode('tmp')
```

###### create the desired columns

```
df['Date'] = df.tmp.str[0]
df['Moon Phase'] = df.tmp.str[1]
df = df.iloc[:, 1:]

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.set_index('Date')

print(df)

               Moon Phase
Date                     
2020-08-18       New Moon
2020-08-25  First Quarter
2020-09-01      Full Moon
2020-09-10  Third Quarter
2020-09-17       New Moon
2020-09-23  First Quarter
2020-10-01      Full Moon
2020-10-09  Third Quarter
2020-10-16       New Moon
2020-10-23  First Quarter
2020-10-31      Full Moon
2020-11-08  Third Quarter
```